# we have a tensor of 10x10 which is encrypted using tenseal library, how to access individual elements or a column or row of encrypted tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

is there any direct or inbuilt method for accessing elements of encrypted tensor

on the plain tensor of TensorFlow we can use slicing and indexing but when we use tenseal library then either its plain tensor or encrypted tensor, slicing and indexing method didnt work on tenseal tensors. can we split a tensor into multiple tensors or we can say that can we make subsets of tensors?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this piece of code for encrypting and decrypting tensors.

```
pip install tenseal==0.1.0a0
import tenseal as ts

# Setup Tenseal context
context = ts.context(
            ts.SCHEME_TYPE.CKKS,
            poly_modulus_degree=8192,
            coeff_mod_bit_sizes=[60, 40, 40, 60]
          )
context.generate_galois_keys()
context.global_scale = 2**40

v1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
v2 = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

# encrypted vectors
enc_v1 = ts.ckks_vector(context, v1)
enc_v2 = ts.ckks_vector(context, v2)

result = enc_v1 + enc_v2
result.decrypt() # ~ [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

result = enc_v1.dot(enc_v2)
result.decrypt() # ~ [10]

matrix = [
  [73, 0.5, 8],
  [81, -5, 66],
  [-100, -78, -2],
  [0, 9, 17],
  [69, 11 , 10],
]
result = enc_v1.matmul(matrix)
result.decrypt() # ~ [157, -90, 153]
```

For more Details, check this page out.
https://pypi.org/project/tenseal/#tutorials

This should work for you.